# What is the difference between System testing and non system testing

Tags: testing

One of my friend got this question during his interview.

Answer (score 0):

To my mind, system testing [tests software and hardware together](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_testing), e.g. running the test on a staging system, which is similar to the productive system.

Non system testing is running the tests in another environment, like your developing machine.